# Azure AD extraction script

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, export-to-csv, export-to-excel, qlikview

Me (and the company I work for) are looking for a script to extract the following information from an AzureAD.

- Accountname
- Username
- Description
- creation date
- last login
- Blocked yes or no
- Date last password change
- Password expiration date
- Administrator yes or no

Futhermore:

- NTFS groups
- Computer SID (OS and version / assigned to which OU / Last time seen online)

And lastly

- Password policy

We require our customers to provide this information when they are subject to a financial audit. Currently we have a working extraction script which give a .csv export which we can import in a qlikview dashboard. With this dashboard we can look for possible security risks. We do not export passwords and do not want passwords of accounts.

I have been looking for such a script for a couple of weeks but can't seem to find one that gives us this result.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Have a look at [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph). That enables you to create such a tool / script. Asking for a script is not a good fit for SO. Please refer to [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good question, but since I needed almost the same information, I will show you how you can start solving your issue, and for others ending up in this question by searching.

Start by installing this https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/2.0.2.4 to your powershell

Then you connect to your [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0).

```
$_adroles = @()
$_docpath = $env:userprofile + '\Documents\ADDirRole.csv'
Get-AzureADDirectoryRole | foreach {
    $_objectid = $_.ObjectId; $rolename = $_.Displayname
    $_adroles += Get-AzureADDirectoryRoleMember -ObjectId $_objectid | select  `
    @{name='RoleName';expression={$rolename}},displayname,UserPrincipalName,UserType,LastDirSyncTime,DirSyncEnabled,mail,accountenabled
}
$_adroles | export-csv $_docpath –NoTypeInformation
```

For more information see: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chadcox/2017/06/30/powershell-useful-azure-ad-queries-using-the-azuread-module/

And the documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#users